# How do I define dynamic matrix using Eigen library?

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, matrix, eigen

I'm trying to define a dynamic Matrix in C++ , using Eigen library . First I get the number of rows and columns as an input (nZ) then I define my Matrix in the following class but it doesn't let me to use (nZ) as the number of rows variable ! Do you have any idea what should I do?

> GetParams Params ;
>
> class Hamiltonian {
>
> public:
>      Hamiltonian();
>      void SetHam0(double,double,int,double)
>      virtual ~Hamiltonian();
>      int nZ = Params.Get_nZ() ;
>
> private:
>      Eigen::MatrixXd U_on = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,1) ;
>      Eigen::MatrixXd Ham0 = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,nZ) ;
>      Eigen::MatrixXd mstar = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,nZ) ;
>      Eigen::MatrixXd U_v  = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,1) ;
>
> };

Comment: `nZ` valuation and all `setZero` calls must be done in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Valuate nZ and all matrices in the constructor :

```
class Hamiltonian {

public:
Hamiltonian();
virtual ~Hamiltonian();

private:
Eigen::MatrixXd U_on;
Eigen::MatrixXd Ham0;
Eigen::MatrixXd mstar;
Eigen::MatrixXd U_v;
int nZ;

};

Hamiltonian::Hamiltonian()
{
  GetParams Params;
  nZ = Params.Get_nZ();

  U_on = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,1) ;
  Ham0 = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,nZ) ;
  mstar = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,nZ) ;
  U_v = Eigen::MatrixXd.setZero(nZ,1) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael . but If I do this , then every time I call My class to access its matrices they will become zero ! am I right ?

Comment: No. The constructor is call only one time.